How to hide port numbers form multiple node Applications hosted on IIS 8
I have multiple node and Go applications running on a Single server, I know if I assign them to 443 I wont require a port number, but I want to do it for multiple applications that are running on the single server example: www.example.com:3000 -> www.example.com, ww1.example.com:3002 - > ww1.example.com and ww3.example.com:3008 -> ww3.example.com. I have searched and found about url rewriting, but it wont work either now I wonder if this is possible. If someone can Point in the right direction I would be grateful Thanks

If you simply use HttpPlatformHandler to host all of them on IIS, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/#references then just configure the sites to bind to the right domain names and port 80/443.

Can you post your url rewrite rule? url rewrite can meet your needs, but you need multiple  url rewrite rules.
